# Align text vertically from three div columns

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

**My purpose is to align the text from the plain divs and the donut chart (text inside) as per the image below. Feel free to completely change the idea of the creation of the donut chart.** 
[image]

I have a template based on flexbox CSS.

What I want is to have all the texts from the three columns (one has a donut chart showing - "THR" text). The snippet below needs to change in order to have all the texts aligned vertically:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);.row{box-sizing:border-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 1 auto;-ms-flex-direction:row;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-right:-1rem;margin-left:-1rem}.col-xs,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-4{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-xs{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}

/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */figure{display:block}html{font-family:'Karla';-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0;overflow:hidden;background: #fff;}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:0}body{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:18px;font-family:'Karla',"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;font-weight:400;background:#fff;line-height:1.4rem}:focus{outline-color:transparent;outline-style:none}.box,.box-first{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;min-height:1rem;margin-bottom:0;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;color:#555555}.box-container{box-sizing:border-box;padding:.5rem}@media only screen and (min-width:48rem){body{font-size:16px}.box,.box-first{padding:1rem}}.row{box-sizing:border-box;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-right:-.5rem;margin-left:-.5rem}.col-xs,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-4{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-xs{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}


.chart-text {
  /*font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;*/
  fill: #000;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}
.chart-number {
  font-size: 0.6em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}
.chart-label {
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  transform: translateY(0.7em);
}
figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  figure {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.figure-content {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}
.figure-content svg {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs">
                        <div>ONE</div>
                        <div style="font-size:15px;">100,000</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs">
                        <div>TWO TWO TWO</div>
                        <div style="font-size:15px;">2,350</div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                  
                  <figure>
  <div class="figure-content">
    <svg width="40%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 42 42" class="donut" aria-labelledby="beers-title beers-desc" role="img">
      <circle class="donut-hole" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff" role="presentation"></circle>
      <circle class="donut-ring" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3" role="presentation"></circle>

      <circle class="donut-segment" cx="21" cy="21" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25" aria-labelledby="donut-segment-1-title donut-segment-1-desc">
      </circle>
      <!-- unused 10% -->
      <g class="chart-text">
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
          THR
        </text>
        <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
          35%
        </text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</figure>
                  
                  <!--
                     <div class="col-xs">
                        <div>VTR</div>
                        <div style="font-size:15px;">57%</div>
                     </div>
                 --> 
                  
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, I have tried using the `figure svg` solution for all three boxes but the text gets cut:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla);.row{box-sizing:border-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 1 auto;-ms-flex-direction:row;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-right:-1rem;margin-left:-1rem}.col-xs,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-4{box-sizing:border-box;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;-webkit-box-flex:0;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:1rem;padding-left:1rem}.col-xs{-webkit-flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;-webkit-box-flex:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.667%;flex-basis:16.667%;max-width:16.667%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.333%;flex-basis:33.333%;max-width:33.333%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.333%;flex-basis:83.333%;max-width:83.333%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}

/*! normalize.css v2.1.3 | MIT License | git.io/normalize */figure{display:block}html{font-family:'Karla';-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0;overflow:hidden;background: #fff;}img{border:0}svg:not(:root){overflow:hidden}figure{margin:0}body{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;margin:0;font-size:18px;font-family:'Karla',"Helvetica Neue Light","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;font-weight:400;background:#fff;line-height:1.4rem}:focus{outline-color:transparent;outline-style:none}.box,.box-first{position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;min-height:1rem;margin-bottom:0;overflow:hidden;text-align:center;color:#555555}.box-container{box-sizing:border-box;padding:.5rem}@media only screen and (min-width:48rem){body{font-size:16px}.box,.box-first{padding:1rem}}.row{box-sizing:border-box;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 1 auto;flex:0 1 auto;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-ms-flex-direction:row;flex-direction:row;-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;margin-right:-.5rem;margin-left:-.5rem}.col-xs,.col-xs-10,.col-xs-12,.col-xs-2,.col-xs-4{box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:0 0 auto;flex:0 0 auto;padding-right:.5rem;padding-left:.5rem}.col-xs{-webkit-box-flex:1;-ms-flex-positive:1;flex-grow:1;-ms-flex-preferred-size:0;flex-basis:0;max-width:100%}.col-xs-2{-ms-flex-preferred-size:16.66666667%;flex-basis:16.66666667%;max-width:16.66666667%}.col-xs-4{-ms-flex-preferred-size:33.33333333%;flex-basis:33.33333333%;max-width:33.33333333%}.col-xs-10{-ms-flex-preferred-size:83.33333333%;flex-basis:83.33333333%;max-width:83.33333333%}.col-xs-12{-ms-flex-preferred-size:100%;flex-basis:100%;max-width:100%}


.chart-text {
  /*font: 16px/1.4em "Montserrat", Arial, sans-serif;*/
  fill: #000;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.25em);
  transform: translateY(0.25em);
}
.chart-number {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-0.25em);
  transform: translateY(-0.25em);
}
.chart-label {
  font-size: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0.7em);
  transform: translateY(0.7em);
}
figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  figure {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
.figure-content {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  align-self: center;
}
.figure-content svg {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="box box-container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                   <figure>
                      <div class="figure-content">
                        <svg width="40%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 68 68" class="donut" >
                          <g class="chart-text">
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
                              ONE
                            </text>
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
                              100,000
                            </text>
                          </g>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                   <figure>
                      <div class="figure-content">
                        <svg width="40%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 68 68" class="donut">
                          <g class="chart-text">
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
                              TWO TWO TWO
                            </text>
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
                              2,350
                            </text>
                          </g>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
               <div class="box-first box-container">
                  <div class="row">
                   <figure>
                      <div class="figure-content">
                        <svg width="40%" height="auto" viewBox="0 0 68 68" class="donut" aria-labelledby="beers-title beers-desc" role="img">
                          <circle class="donut-hole" cx="34" cy="34" r="15.91549430918954" fill="#fff" role="presentation"></circle>
                          <circle class="donut-ring" cx="34" cy="34" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#d2d3d4" stroke-width="3" role="presentation"></circle>

                          <circle class="donut-segment" cx="34" cy="34" r="15.91549430918954" fill="transparent" stroke="#ce4b99" stroke-width="3" stroke-dasharray="40 60" stroke-dashoffset="25" aria-labelledby="donut-segment-1-title donut-segment-1-desc">
                          </circle>
                          <!-- unused 10% -->
                          <g class="chart-text">
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-number">
                              THR
                            </text>
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" class="chart-label">
                              35%
                            </text>
                          </g>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                    </figure>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible as it stands. There is NO CSS mechanism or property to align elements that do not share a parent element.

Comment: @Paulie_D It seems that there are two ways (I am close). One is based on the answer below. The fiddles are: https://jsfiddle.net/radomer/dsc1tqgL/ and https://jsfiddle.net/radomer/x1Lrpu2t/

Comment: That aligns elements in their containers, **not to each other.**

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes. So, the final output will look responsive. The texts will be at the same line and the font-size the same. My only issue is the font-size at the moment. Thinking of using JS but it will be more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to vertically center align the first and second col.

You can do so with flex with a `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: center`

```
<div class="col-xs-4" style=" display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; ">
```

I added some inline style to show you show it's done. Feel free to reorganize the inline styles into some classes.

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/dLjwmhvk/2/

Comment: the font size is not the same in all the three divs. How can I keep the texts in the same line and maintain the font size as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this

```
.box-first { display:table; width:100%; height:100%; }
.box-first > div { display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; }
```

Comment: I applied that to the first snippet and it didn't change a lot of things.